# How to replace the entity that the objectstatemanager is tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I am getting the "An object with the same key already exists" on an update attempt while trying to attach an entity.Lazy loading is turned on.
I googled, and found no real solution to this problem. My best solution would be to replace the entry in the object state manager, but I can not find anywhere how to replace it. Is it possible at all?

the problems occurs when I create an instance of object A (has a collection of Object B) in one context, and the B objects in another context. When I try to attach both of them it breaks.
Is there a way to tell EF when to replace the entry that it is tracking. Could it maybe be possible that it would allow the replacement when I would set the duplicated entitykey entries objectstate to modified.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to your problem.

**1. Detecting if an entity is already being tracked by the context.**

If you have two references to the same instance of an entity it is easy to see if it is being tracked.

```
Boolean isTracked = context.MyEntities.Local.Contains(myEntity);
```

If you instead have two instances of an entity that is conceptually the same because they have the same key then things can be more difficult.

```
Boolean isTracked = context.MyEntities.Local.Any(x=>x.Id == myEntity.Id);
```

Or alternatively using an `EqualityComparer<T>`:

```
public class MyEntityEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<MyEntity>
{
   public override bool Equals(MyEntity x, MyEntity y)
   {
      return x.Id == y.Id;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode(MyEntity obj)
   {
      return obj.Id;
   }
}

context.MyEntities.Local.Contains(myEntity, new MyEntityEqualityComparer());
```

**2. Switching out the entity being tracked.**

This can be achieved like so:

```
context.Entry<MyEntity>(entityToReplace).State = EntityState.Detached;
context.MyEntities.Attach(entityToAdd);
```

However, before you do all this you should look at your application design. Having to juggle entities between contexts can be a sign that you are not grouping tasks into appropriate units of work where you could operate on a single context.

Comment: Seems legit. 
I did one project with a single context object and never again. ;)

Some things here, I will have to do in a different way. On the one hand that for instance "Entry" came since EF 4.1 (I use 4.0), on the other hand, I created generic classes that I use for ataching. Anyway I think this might work. THNX